# Deleting a message after it was copied and send to another Channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

im trying to figure out how to delete a message, after it was copied and send to another Channel

My Code for that is:

```
bot.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("t!logout")) {
    var str = message.content.slice(" ");
    bot.channels.cache
      .get("8786607442820137469")
      .send(
        `New Message from: ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator} ` +
          str
      );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the code you are looking for:

```js
bot.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("t!logout")) {
        var str = message.content.slice(" ");

        // Replace this with the channel ID 
        const channelToSendId = "CHANNEL_ID";

        // Wait for the bot to send the message
        await bot.channels.cache
            .get(channelToSendId)
            .send(
                `New Message from: ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator} ` +
                    str
            );

        // Delete the message
        message.delete();
    }
});
```

If you wanted to send a embed you could do something like

```js
bot.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("t!logout")) {
        var str = message.content.slice(" ");

        // Replace this with the channel ID 
        const channelToSendId = "CHANNEL_ID";
      
       const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setAuthor(`New Message from: ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)
       .setDescription(`Content: ${str}`)

        // Wait for the bot to send the message
        await bot.channels.cache
            .get(channelToSendId)
            .send(embed);

        // Delete the message
        message.delete();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried you're code and it's working but i have another problem. I want to send an embed Message instead of a normal Message and i have no idea how i'm supposed to do that with that Code. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Done @IneedHelp

Comment: Hey, i have antoher question. I want to use the Bot on different Servers and obviously the Channel ID i'm using to send the message in another Channel isn't working on the other Server. Is there any Chance you have a solution for that problem?